# Print specific line number only if match in sed

Tags: shell, sed, line, match

How do you print a (specific) line only if there is a match in `sed` (Linux stream editor)? Let's say I have line three that I would like to print only if it meets the match criteria; how can I print this?

I am piping a command's output to `sed`, and would prefer not to use `sed`'s output to pipe to `sed` again:

```
| sed -ne ''"$currline"'p' | sed -n '/state/p'`
```

Also, I was assigning the output to a variable with backticks.

---

Given inputs A and B, and the search pattern `state`, the output for A should be the line `3 stateless` (note that 3 is part of the data), and for B should be nothing:

```
Input A              Input B
1 state              1 state
2 statement          2 statement
3 stateless          3 statless
4 stated             4 stated
5 estate             5 estate
```

Comment: Anything against `grep`?

Comment: please post examples with expected output

Comment: You want the line or the number of the line as output ? This is not clear for me

Answer (score 6):

```
sed -n '3{/state/p;}' $file
```

The 3 matches line 3; the actions on line 3 are 'if you find `/state/`, print'; the `-n` prevents general printing of lines.

Also, you should avoid backticks; it is better to use the `var=$(cmd1 | cmd2)` notation than `` var=`cmd1 | cmd2` `` notation.

Comment: Brilliant, I was looking just for that.  Thanks a lot for answering, I hope the OP selects your answer.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand you want to match two criterias, a specific line number an a pattern. You can achieve it in one `sed` command.

Assuming `infile` with content:

```
one
two
three
four
five
```

And if you want to print the fourth line if it matches `ur`, use:

```
sed -ne '4 { /ur/ { p; q } }' infile
```

That yields:

```
four
```

Answer (score 2):

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
awk 'NR==3 && /pattern/{print;exit}'
```

**NOTE**

- *pattern* is a `regex`
- `exit` avoid to parse the whole file

Answer (score 2):

sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line but for anything else just use awk:

```
awk 'NR==3 && /state/'
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '3!d;/state/q;Q' file
```

or

```
sed -ne '3!b' -e '/state/p' -e 'q' file
```